# When running the automatic generated test runners parallely using testng facing the below exception

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber, testng

> **Below is the latest Automatically generated runner files**

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(strict = false,
features = {"C:/Users/mbethu/IdeaProjects/comparalleltestng/src/main/java/java/features/HomePage.feature"},
plugin = {"html:target/cucumber/1.html"},
monochrome = true,
tags = {},
glue = { "java.stepdefinitions" })
public class Parallel01IT extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}


import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;

@CucumberOptions(strict = false,
features = {"C:/Users/mbethu/IdeaProjects/comparalleltestng/src/main/java/java/features/Login.feature"},
plugin = {"html:target/cucumber/2.html"},
monochrome = true,
tags = {},
glue = { "java.stepdefinitions" })
public class Parallel02IT extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

> **Below is latest testng.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="3">   <!-- how many scenarios we can execute at a time is mentioned bt data-provider-thread-count-->
    <test  name="ChromeTest" thread-count="5"  >
        <!--  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>-->
        <packages>
            <package name="target.generated-test-sources.cucumber"/>
        </packages>
    </test> <!-- Test -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

> **Below is the latest POM.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.parallel</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.parallel.testng</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generateRunners</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Mandatory -->
                        <!-- comma separated list of package names to scan for glue code -->
                        <glue>java.stepdefinitions</glue>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
                        <featuresDirectory>C:\Users\mbethu\IdeaProjects\comparalleltestng\src\main\java\java\features</featuresDirectory>
                        <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
                        <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber</cucumberOutputDir>
                        <!-- comma separated list of output formats json,html,rerun.txt -->
                        <format>html</format>
                        <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
                        <strict>false</strict>
                        <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
                        <monochrome>true</monochrome>
                        <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property you can pass ANDed tags like "@tag1","@tag2" and ORed tags like "@tag1,@tag2,@tag3" -->
                       <!-- <tags></tags>-->
                        <!-- If set to true, only feature files containing the required tags shall be generated. -->
                        <filterFeaturesByTags>false</filterFeaturesByTags>
                        <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of default JUnit ones. -->
                        <useTestNG>true</useTestNG>
                        <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 'simple' or 'feature-title' -->
                        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
                        <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
                        <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
                        <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
                        <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
                        <!-- This is optional, required only if you want to specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a relative path) -->
                        <!--<customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>-->
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!--<forkCount>5</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>-->

                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src\test\java\testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
               <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
               <testErrorIgnore>true</testErrorIgnore>
               <includes>
                   <include>src\test\java\testng.xml</include>
                   <!--<include>**/*IT.class</include>-->
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-testng -->
        <!--    <dependency>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
             <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
             <version>2.22.1</version>
         </dependency>-->

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>-->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <!-- <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
        <!--      <dependency>
               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
               <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
               <version>1.2.5</version>
               <type>pom</type>
           </dependency>-->

           <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
        <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
      <!--  <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

> Below are older files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.parallel</groupId>
<artifactId>com.parallel.testng</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>generateRunners</id>
<phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
 <goals>
 <goal>generateRunners</goal>
 </goals>
 <configuration>
 <!-- Mandatory -->
 <!-- comma separated list of package names to scan for glue code -->
 <glue>java.stepdefinitions</glue>

 <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test- 
 sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
 <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
                <featuresDirectory>C:\Users\mbethu\IdeaProjects\comparalleltestng\src\main\java\java\features</featuresDirectory>
 <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->

<cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber</cucumberOutputDir>
 <!-- comma separated list of output formats json,html,rerun.txt -->
 <format>json,html</format>
 <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
 <strict>false</strict>
 <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
 <monochrome>true</monochrome>
 <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property you can 
pass ANDed tags like "@tag1","@tag2" and ORed tags like 
"@tag1,@tag2,@tag3" -->
<tags></tags>
<!-- If set to true, only feature files containing the required tags 
shall be generated. -->
<filterFeaturesByTags>false</filterFeaturesByTags>
<!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of default JUnit ones. -->
<useTestNG>true</useTestNG>
<!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of 
'simple' or 'feature-title' -->
<namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
<!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
<namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
<!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per 
scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
<parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
 <!-- This is optional, required only if you want to specify a custom 
 template for the generated sources (this is a relative path) -->
 <!--<customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom- 
 runner.vm</customVmTemplate>-->
 </configuration>
 </execution>
 </executions>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.19.1</version>
 <configuration>
 <!-- <forkCount>5</forkCount>
 <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>-->

 <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src\test\java\testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>

            <parallel>classes</parallel>
            <threadCount>10</threadCount>
           <!-- <includes>
                <include>**/*IT.class</include>
            </includes>-->
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm-deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/gherkin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.6</version>
  </dependency>-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

> Below are the errors i am getting when i run the command
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
> [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  12.820 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2019-04-20T16:15:56+05:30 [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   (default-test) on project com.parallel.testng: Execution default-test
>   of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   failed: There was an error in the forked process [ERROR]
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SimpleReportEntry.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V
>   [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestSuite.startTestSuite(TestSuite.java:46)
>   [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:74)
>   [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
>   [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
>   [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
>   [ERROR]         at
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   (default-test) on project com.parallel.testng: Execution default-test
>   of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test
>   failed: There was an error in the forked process
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SimpleReportEntry.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestSuite.startTestSuite(TestSuite.java:46)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:74)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
>
> ```
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> ```
>
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:282)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:406)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
>   default-test of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed:
>   There was an error in the forked process java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SimpleReportEntry.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestSuite.startTestSuite(TestSuite.java:46)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:74)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
>
> ```
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
> at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
> ```
>
> (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at
>
> ```
>  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
> ```
>
> (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:282)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:406)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was
>   an error in the forked process java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.report.SimpleReportEntry.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)V
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestSuite.startTestSuite(TestSuite.java:46)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:74)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
>           at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
>
> ```
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork (ForkStarter.java:584)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork (ForkStarter.java:460)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:229)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run (ForkStarter.java:201)
> at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider
> ```
>
> (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1026)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked
>   (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute (AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:282)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:406)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) [ERROR] [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Comment: U should upgrade to latest cucumber. Look up cucumber.io in maven and use version 4 atleast. Parallel running is now inbuilt. Refer to this to run in parallel https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/testng/README.md. It is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

*You are using info.cukes dependency which is pretty old and support cucumber till v 1.2.5 only and No more support on this after 12 September 2016 and that's the reason you have to still use cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin and doing lots of configuration required to generate individual runner per feature file on the fly.*

*Please try to follow & implement Cucumber V 4.0.X onwards not only to implement parallel execution rather to keep you updated as well and below are the steps to implement this.*

***1.Adding correct set of dependency. I have followed JUnit during the implementation.***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

***2.Adding Maven-Surefire-Plugin under POM.XML***

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
        <reuserForks>false</reuserForks>
        <testErrorIgnore>true</testErrorIgnore>   
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*RunCukeTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note - TestNG dependency causes Surefire to ignore JUnit wrapper class. Remove all the TestNG dependencies if not required at all or you can take a call to 2 define 2 execution one for TestNG & other for JUnit and disable one as per your need. People using JUnit faces issue everything is ok but still single test run. So we have to keep this as well.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I have updated POM.xml with the latest dependencies. Now when i run the command "mvn clean test" it says the Build is Success but my tests are not executed.It gives me the output in console as below                                [INFO] Running TestSuite
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.637 s - in 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: Please share your runner file code and if possible then pom xml as well to understand what could be the issue.

Comment: I have updated my latest testRunners files, testNG files and POM.xml file.

Comment: I have updated my latest testRunners files, testNG files and POM.xml file

Comment: Please do not use cucumber-jvm parallel plugin. As we suggest please use Cucumber 4.0.0 or any above version to implement parallel execution.